# AWS API Gateway - Enable caching per-request

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to enable/disable caching a request through the AWS API Gateway in the response of the request?

According to this document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html It appears that the most granular one can get in defining cache settings is enabling/disabling caching for a specific API function. What I am wanting to do is allow the response for the API request to dictate whether or not it is to be cached. (i.e. I want my end API program to be able to determine if a response for a given request should be cached).

Is this possible, and if so how can it be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your own CloudFront distribution, with the API Gateway endpoint as the origin server.  CloudFront web distributions respect `Cache-Control` headers from the origin server.  If you customize that response, this should accomplish your objective.

API Gateway, as you may already know, runs behind some of the CloudFront infrastructure already, so this might seem redundant, but this appears to be the only way to take control of the caching behavior.

Comment: Yeah that does seem a little roundabout. Will this add extra latency to my app considering now requests are travelling through two layers of CloudFront?